# how to limit the amount of simultaneous connections to a microservice with node.js

Tags: node.js, microservices

I needed to create an batch job executer, the front-end will make a lot of calls to the backend based on a file(for each line on the file they will make one call), then the backend will make at least 2 PUT calls(on diferent micro services) for each front-end call.
Everthing works fine, until i decide to test, and one of the micro services stop working, and the owner came to me saying i have created too much simultanly connections.
So this is my problem, how limit the total amount of simultanly connections to this api, since i will have multiple users on this system
Currently i'm using express.js and axios.

Comment: This is a load-balancer or front-end server concern. You usually deploy Node.js behind some kind of server layer like [Nginx](http://nginx.org) which can do the rate limiting as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the resources you are exposing in the back-end microservice, one canonical way to achieve what you are trying to do is **caching**. That way, multiple front-ends can share the result of a single back-end operation, provided that the data is still relevant.

I would have a look at the MDN's documentation on `Cache-Control` which provide the basics for how caching is done over HTTP. Another common tool for this case is using a reverse proxy like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/), which also gets the added bonus of rate limiting.

Comment: i cant use cache, all the calls are PUTs